# Processing a single file with multiple record types in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have data which looks somewhat like the following (`data.txt`):

```
01,"Alice","The Cat"
02,Yes
03,2000,01,01
01,"Bob","The Dog"
02,No
03,2001,01,04
```

The first two characters per row give a `record_type` which then determines the schema of the row. The data is unpredictable - there can be multiple or no instances of a particular record type per "block". The file is a `.csv` and qualified with `"` and in reality has millions of records.

I wish to wrangle this file type, using `pyspark`, into multiple files - one per record type. I have attempted this with an `rdd` and looping approach but feel like there may be an alternative better approach available. At present this takes 30 minutes to produce all files.

```
import csv
record_types = ["01", "02", "03"]
rdd = sc.textFile("data.txt")
rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x))

for r in record_types:
  records = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == r)
  sdf = spark.createDataFrame(records)
  sdf.write.mode('overwrite').csv(f"{r}.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Dataframe with record_type as first column and all remaining as second column, like given below,

```
input_df=spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("test.txt").map(lambda x : tuple([x[0:2], x[3:]])))

+-----------+-----------------+
|    _1     |       _2        | 
+-----------+-----------------+
|         01|"Alice","The Cat"|
|         02|              Yes|
|         03|       2000,01,01|
|         01|  "Bob","The Dog"|
|         02|               No|
|         03|       2001,01,04|
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Then, filter the rows based on type and store them.

```
types=["01","02","03"]
for type in types:
    input_df.filter(col("_1") == type).write.mode('overwrite').csv(f"{type}_rows.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work a lot faster.

```
record_types = ["01", "02", "03"]
df = spark.read.csv("data.txt")
for r in record_types:
    df.where('_1' == r).write.mode('overwrite').csv(f"{r}.csv")
```

Comment: You'll notice that this truncates the length of `record_type = "03"` - we end up missing a data item.